# AWS VPC SSH security group configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I'm setting up a test VPC on AWS to see how I like different configurations.

Using the default Scenario 2 configuration:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

I'm not sure what the best practice process for accessing members of the subnet is. You can ssh into the NAT and then ssh into the instance in the subnet, but this of course requires having the pem keys for that instance on the NAT, which makes me uncomfortable.

Have I miss understood the configurations of the security groups, and should be able to ssh directly into the members of the subnet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, instances in private VPC subnets do not have inbound access from the Internet and cannot be accessed directly. You can assign elastic IPs to instances in private subnets and inbound traffic would be routed to it. However, outbound return traffic would never reach the source since the NAT won't route asymmetric traffic.

There are at least two options for accessing those systems via SSH:

1. Use a bastion host in a public subnet to jump to the instances in the private subnet. The NAT could serve as this bastion, or you could set up another instance. You can have your private key on the bastion, or you can use the `ForwardAgent` option in your SSH configuration to use the private key from the bastion without requiring the key file to be present.
2. Establish a VPN from your network to the VPC using a VPN gateway. Allow access in the VPC security groups from your network's address space to the instances in the private subnet. You can then SSH to the private instances as if they're local to your network.

Leaving the private keys on the bastion host shouldn't make you uncomfortable if you harden the bastion sufficiently using security group rules, local firewalls, and other standard system security techniques.

Comment: Your answer pretty much sums it up but: a private subnet is an abstract thing in AWS - it depends on your networking setup (routing tables etc). An EC2 instance in such a 'private' subnet can of course have an Elastic IP and as long as you have a NAT instance to handle outgoing traffic, incoming traffic will be handled transparently due to the EIP (there's a hidden SNAT behind that).

Comment: I actually don't think that a VPC private subnet is abstract. The docs are clear that a "public subnet" routes through an internet gateway and a "private subnet" doesn't. But it's true that the reason you don't access private instances directly is more complex than I originally stated. I amended my answer to be a bit more clear about EIPs and instances in private subnets.